# Rewriting Stirling Number generating function for non-fixed $k$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

The Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind can be found through the ordinary generating function

$$\frac{x^k}{(1-x)(1-2x)...(1-kx)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {S(n,k)x^n}$$

Clearly here the g.f is for some fixed positive integer $k$.  It has been shown by Gessel (and others probably) that

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)...(1-mx)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {S(m+n,n)x^n}$$

It appears here that the fixed integer is no longer fixed, so how can this be valid?  My initial thoughts were this:  Dividing by $x^k$ in the first equation yields

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)...(1-kx)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {S(n,k)x^{n-k}}$$

and by a change of variables, this will equal

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)...(1-kx)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {S(n+k,k)x^n}$$

which is close, but we are still seeing a fixed $k$ as the second input.  Does anyone know why this is valid for an indexed input?

Comment: That second generating function simply doesn't hold. Take for example $m=2$ then expanding the LHS up to $x^5$ using [sage](http://sagecell.sagemath.org) we have $$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)}=63 \, x^{5} + 31 \, x^{4} + 15 \, x^{3} + 7 \, x^{2} + 3 \, x + 1$$ compare this with the RHS $$\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}S(n+2,n)x^n &=S(2,0)+S(3,1)x+S(4,2)x^2+S(5,3)x^3+S(6,4)x^4+S(7,5)x^5+\cdots\\ &=x+7x^2+25x^3+65x^4+140x^5+\cdots\end{align}$$ These coefficients are tabulated [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: I didn't think so.  [Here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022314X04001416/1-s2.0-S0022314X04001416-main.pdf?_tid=130de75e-2c11-11e7-85f9-00000aab0f02&acdnat=1493383930_2ebc07df7bc6f505ecbb53e149811af2) is the paper.  I was originally under the impression it should be $S(m+n,m)$, but it's peppered throughout the paper.

Comment: @N.Shales, if you see the paper, it definitely states $S(m+n,n)$, right?

Comment: That's what it says. However I think that is a mistake, the paper says that it should simply be a transformed version of the first generating function. I concur with your result $$\frac{1}{\textstyle{\prod_{j=1}^{k}(1-jx)}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}S(n+k,k)x^n$$ as this checks out in sage, if you look at my example for $m=2$ you will see this generates the second column of the Stirling numbers in the [wiki link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) as it should according to *your* RHS.

Comment: I'm glad you concur.  I tried everything at first and was getting frustrated.  I thought it was a typo, but you never think that these guys make mistakes.   Thank you for your help.